# How to use environment per rule in snakemake?

Tags: python, conda, snakemake

I have a workflow with several rules. One rule needs a py2 dependent tool. Thus I would like to specify a certain conda environment for this specific rule but I get the an error for this.

Environment: Debian 8, Conda 4.3.25 and snakemake 3.11.2

Here is how I run my workflow:

1. Create default environment with conda env create --name myworkflow --file environment.yml
2. source activate myworkflow
3. snakemake -ps workflow.snake --use-conda

It is trying to create the environment, but then runs into an error.
If I run

```
   conda create env --name python2_tool --file environment2.yaml
```

from within the activated environment there is no error. But with the --prefix it is not working.

So I am wondering what is going wrong here?

The error looks as followed:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::icu-54.1-0'
OSError(95, 'Operation not supported')            
Attempting to roll back.                 
OSError(95, 'Operation not supported')
```

The rule causing problems looks like that:

```
rule annotation:
  input: "{condition}.bed"
  output: "{condition}_annotated.bed"
  threads: 8
  conda: 
    "envs/environment2.yml"
  shell:
    "wrapper.sh -i {input} -o {output} -c {threads}"
```

Comment: This looks like a conda bug. What OS are you using?

Comment: We are using Debian 8

Comment: Besides that we are usingConda 4.3.25 and snakemake 3.11.2

Comment: Hi Johannes, we figured out that the error occurs because our shared file system is ntfs based, which does not support symlinks. However, the conda env create call tries to create symlinks. Is it possible to add a snakemake flag to specify the prefix path, such that the environments are created elsewhere but not in the .snakemake folder? Best, Annika